# Many to many EF core - Unable to determine the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm trying to solve a many to many relationship in EF core, but I keep getting an exception (Unable to determine the raltionship represented by navigation property 'Category.contacts' of type List)

I'm learning EF core and I've read a lot of posts about this issue already but I cannot solve it on my own. I believe it will be asked on the exam.

I've made a class to solve the many to many problem, but how do I configure this correctly using the fluent api?

This is my code:

```
public class Contact{
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}

public class Category{
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}

public class ContactCategory{
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Contact Contact {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}

//Inside the DbContext class:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactCategory>().HasKey(x => new {x.PersonId, x.CategoryId});
}
```

The exception itself:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Contacts.UI.CA.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Category.Contacts' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The many-to-many relationship is a tricky one; we need to understand how these kinds of
relationships are built. Usually, we will build two different entities that require a many-to-many relationship, create an entity that will be purely used to join the first two entities, and then map one-to-many between this entity (created to join two separate one-to-many relationships) and the two entities (created first) separately:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ContactCategory> ContactCategories {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactCategory> ContactCategories { get; set; }
}

public class ContactCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId {get; set;}
    public Contact Contact {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

The `Contact` and `Category` entities require many-to-many relationships for which the `ContactCategory` entity is created, and its only job is to join the Contact and Category entities.

We should configure the relationship in the Fluent API in two different one-to-many
relationships between the Contact and ContactCategory and Category and ContactCategory entities. The HasForeignKey method doesn't need to be generic, since one-to-many relationships don't need to mark the dependent type explicitly:

The many-to-many relationship between Contact and Category entities require the following
configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<ContactCategory>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Category)
    .WithMany(x => x.ContactCategories)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<ContactCategory>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Contact)
    .WithMany(x => x.ContactCategories)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ContactId);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution (which worked perfectly) and for the explanation, I know understand much better how this concept works and I've managed to complete the rest of the exercise :)

Comment: If you're also here on 2024 onwards: through the [discovery conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions) the now the fluent configuration is not needed anymore, nor the third join class. EF Core now manages the creation of the third table automagically.